# Private variable in Factory with overlap name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `someVar` in `MyData` factory that is private. Only `get()` function can return that variable. I also have a callback (using `$timeout`) to change that variable after 1 second.

The trick is in this code where the callback variable is same naming as the private variable `someVar`.

```
  myTask(function(someVar) {
    this.someVar = someVar;
  });
```

If I change their names to be different, it works. But if I use `this.someVar` to reference the private variable of the factory, it doesn't work. **So how do I reference private variable in factory if the names could overlap with callback?**

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/n7ZdOLMfpiSflb6F9V5r?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{someVar}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="get()">Get MyData.someVar</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyData) {
  $scope.someVar = 0;

  MyData.runTask();

  $scope.get = function() {
    alert(MyData.get);
  }
});

app.factory('MyData', function($timeout) {
  var someVar = 1;

  return {
    runTask: function() {
      function myTask(callback) {
        $timeout(function() {
          callback(2);
        }, 1000);        
      }

      myTask(function(someVar) {
        this.someVar = someVar;
        alert('After 1 sec. someVar = ' + someVar + ' and this.someVar = ' + this.someVar);
      });
    },
    get: someVar
  }
});
```

Comment: The function parameter always shadows the `var someVar` from the outer scope. The only thing you can do is omit/rename either. The name of the property (`.someVar`) is totally unrelated.

Comment: Isn't there a way to reference the context `this` of the factory somehow??

Comment: Not unless you introduce a variable holding it. But I don't think that's what you want anyway, the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is different from the *scope* that holds the local variables.

Comment: hmm I hope there is a workaround or some sort of tricks.. should I delete this question then?